# Virtual attributes in plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, virtual-attribute

I need some help with virtual attributes. This code works fine but how do I use it inside a plugin. The goal is to add this methods to all classes that uses the plugin.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :title, :permalink

  def title
    if @title 
      @title
    elsif self.page
      self.page.title
    else 
      ""
    end
  end

  def permalink
    if @permalink
      @permalink
    elsif self.page
      self.page.permalink
    else
      ""
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the plugin generator to get started.

```
script/generate plugin acts_as_page
```

You can then add a module which defines `acts_as_page` and extends it into all models.

```
# in plugins/acts_as_page/lib/acts_as_page.rb
module ActsAsPage
  def acts_as_page
    # ...
  end
end

# in plugins/acts_as_page/init.rb
class ActiveRecord::Base
  extend ActsAsPage
end
```

This way the acts_as_page method is available as a class method to all models and you can define any behavior into there. You could do something like this...

```
module ActsAsPage
  def acts_as_page
    attr_writer :title, :permalink
    include Behavior
  end

  module Behavior
    def title
      # ...
    end

    def permalink
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

And then when you call acts_as_page in the model...

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_page
end
```

It will define the attributes and add the methods. If you need things to be a bit more dynamic (such as if you want the `acts_as_page` method to take arguments which changes the behavior) try out the solution I present in [this Railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/33-making-a-plugin).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I get this error: active_record/base.rb:1959:in `method_missing': private method `attr_writer' called for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)

Let me try to be more specific:

I want to be able to add this to my model: 

acts_as_page

Every model that uses this plugin should get two virtual attributes (title and permalink) which is used to create or update a page model in the before_save callback inside the plugin. 

Everything works fine but I don't get the title and permalink values.

I would paste the code but I'm running out of characters :)

Comment: I updated the answer to better fit your requirements. I had forgotten attr_writer was private, but that shouldn't be a problem with this new solution.

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot that I needed to extend my module into ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want a Module for this

```
# my_methods.rb 
module MyMethods
  def my_method_a
    "Hello"
  end
end
```

The you want to include it into the classes you want to use it for.

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyMethods
end

> m = MyClass.new
> m.my_method_a
=> "Hello!"
```

Take a look [here](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/12/ruby-instance-and-class-methods-from.html) for more information on mixing in modules.  You can put the module wherever in a plugin if you like, just ensure its named correctly so Rails can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a module structure like `YourPlugin::InstanceMethods` and include it this module like this:

```
module YourPlugin
  module InstanceMethods
    # your methods
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.__send__(:include, YourPlugin::InstanceMethods)
```

You have to use `__send__` to make your code Ruby 1.9 compatible. The `__send__` line is usually placed at the `init.rb` file on your plugin root directory.